# Does Azure IoT Edge work on any Windows 10 version

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Is it possible to run the Azure IoT Edge gateway container based on 1709 on a Windows 10 LTSB (1607) operating system or can Azure IoT Edge only run with a CBB version of Window 10?

Answer (score 5):

For Azure IoT Edge Windows containers, Azure IoT Edge public preview requires Windows Fall Creators Update (1709). Windows containers are available with LTSB (1607) but are considered to be for development use only.

Using Linux containers, any Windows version which is supported by Docker can be used.